# Programmers Editors on Windows for Indic language editing

Tags: editor, indic

We're going to be building some J2ME apps and Java/Rails webapps which will have a Kannada(a south indian language, for those who don't know much about India) UI. The UI and the data will both be in Kannada for these apps.

So, we will need to write code containing some of these language text in the source code. I find it irritating that neither emacs nor XEmacs OR Jedit can edit any of these languages :-(

Someone mentioned that a variant of Emacs can do it except I don't know if it works on Windows and where to get hold of it.

I know notepad can do the trick BUT it's not a programmer's editor.

P.S : I am an EMacs guy but will be open to using other programmer editors.

P.P.S : This should work on Windows Vista/Windows 7. I wouldn't mind using VirtualBox or VMWare to boot into Linux to use an Linux Editor, if that is the only option I have!

Comment: What's the problem with jedit?

Comment: jedit cannot render my language whereas as "Johannes Rossel" below suggested, eclipse (using SWT) works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering it's Java you're using: Have you tried Eclipse? I know it's not an editor and might be a little overkill when one is used to Emacs, but it uses SWT which in turn uses the OS's native font rendering. And at least my browser shows that the Uniscribe can display Kannada just fine.

Another option might be [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/about.php).

Comment: using notepad(on windows), I can write and display kannada just fine. But it is NOT a programmer's editor.

Well, I tried eclipse. It works as you said

Comment: I haven't suggested Notepad anywhere. You ruled that out in your question already.

Comment: But notepad++ cannot even render the ₹ symbol :-|

Comment: @MilindR: This answer predates the ₹ symbol even existing by half a year.

Answer (score 2):

> So, we will need to write code containing some of these language text in the source code.

I think any Windows editor that supports *UTF-8* will be able to do this. There should be plenty to choose from.

I'm the as the author of the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/) editor and just recently *UTF-8* support was added so I would expect Zeus should be able to do exactly this. But if it doesn't feel free to report a bug on the Zeus forum.

> P.S : I am an EMacs guy but open to using other programmer editors in this situation.

Zeus has a *Emacs* keyboard emulation mode ;)

Comment: Hi jussij,

  thanks for your suggestion -- will evaluate Zeus. This question was kinda answered in the original post(Eclipse is the answers).