# Programmers Editors on Windows for Indic language editing

Tags: text-editor, indic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmers Editors on Windows for Indic language editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026252/programmers-editors-on-windows-for-indic-language-editing)

Hi All,

We're going to be building some J2ME apps and J2ee/Rails webapps which will have a Kannada(a south indian language, for those who don't know much about India) UI. The UI and the data will both be in Kannada for these apps.

So, we will need to write code containing some of these language text in the source code. I find it irritating that neither emacs nor XEmacs OR Jedit can edit any of these languages :-(

Someone mentioned that a variant of Emacs can do it except I don't know if it works on Windows and where to get hold of it.

I know notepad can do the trick BUT it's not a programmer's editor.

P.S : I am an EMacs guy but open to using other programmer editors in this situation.
P.P.S : This should work on Windows Vista/Windows 7. I wouldn't mind using VirtualBox or VMWare to boot into Linux to use an Linux Editor, if that is the only option I have!

Thank you,

BR,
~A